# Storing the XMLA output to a file or any SQL table

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssas, ssis-2012, ssas-2012

**Requirement**: Run the below XMLA script on a particular node of SQL server 2012 and store the output data in a file or an SQL table

```
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
<RequestType>DISCOVER_XML_METADATA</RequestType>
<Restrictions>
    <RestrictionList>
        <ObjectExpansion>ExpandObject</ObjectExpansion>
    </RestrictionList>
</Restrictions>
<Properties>
    <PropertyList>
    </PropertyList>
</Properties>
```

I'm not finding any component in SSIS that could run the XMLA script and store the results. let me know is it possible in any other ways.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139988.aspx

Comment: @lad2025 - the link doesnt provide any idea about storing the output of the XMLA queries

Comment: Do you want to store as XML or flatten out relevant info as columns like dimension name and ID?

Comment: @GregGalloway - I need the info about the last process datetime. it would be really helpful if I get tat info directly. If not I can extract it from the xml if it is stored any where in a file or a sql table.

Comment: Have you tried the SSAS [DMVs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230820.aspx)?  You can query them from an SQL database by creating a linked-server connection to the SSAS server and using OPENQUERY.

Answer (score 0):

Like @sebTHU said you could use a SSAS DMV:

```
Select [CUBE_NAME], LAST_DATA_UPDATE from $system.MDSCHEMA_CUBES
```

However, if you want to list all the databases and their last processed date, install [ASSP](http://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DiscoverXmlMetadata&referringTitle=XmlaDiscover) and then run this:

```
CALL ASSP.DiscoverXmlMetadataFull("\Databases\Database", "" ,"<ObjectExpansion>ExpandObject</ObjectExpansion>")
```

You could use a linked server or a .NET source component in SSIS.

Comment: I tried the DMV's, but I need the Database ID's as well.

Comment: I added another approach that would require the ASSP assembly in order to get a flattened data set with Database ID and list all databases.